# How to use sparselengthssum in caffe2 for categorical data ?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sparse-matrix, categorical-data, caffe2

I am trying to convert categorical data to numerical data. caffe2 has few new operators for the same. I am interested in using sparselenthssum. But the caffe2 docs does not have an example use case. How to use sparelengthssum for categorical data?

https://caffe2.ai/docs/operators-catalogue.html#sparselengthssum.